# Spring boot jpa specification filter records of child entity from parent entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, criteria-api

I have two entities A and B where A is the parent and B is the child. I want to filter records using JPA specifications like Specification.

Their relation is Entity B is having reference to A. I want to apply left join on Entity A using JPA Criteria Builder API. Is it possible to achieve that ?

Here is my Parent entity class

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private Long parentId;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    // constructor, getter and setters
}
```

Here is my child entity class

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long childId;
    private String childName;
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    // constructor, getter and setters
}
```

I want to achieve something like this below code, just want to filter each record based on the `childName` of the Child entity from Parent Specification.

```
@Component
public class ParentSpecification {
    public Specification<Parent> getParentSpecification(Map<String, String> filterValues) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Root<Child> from = query.from(Child.class);
            from.join("parent", JoinType.LEFT);

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            filterValues.forEach((attribute, value) -> {
                if (attribute.equalsIgnoreCase("childName") && value != null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(from.get("childName"), "%" + value + "%"));
                }
            });
            return query.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]))).getRestriction();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources online on this topic.

Example:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Author> root = cq.from(Author.class);
Join<Object, Object> book = root.join(Author_.BOOKS, JoinType.LEFT);
cq.multiselect(root, book);
 
ParameterExpression<String> pLastName = cb.parameter(String.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(Author_.LAST_NAME), pLastName));
 
TypedQuery<Tuple> q = em.createQuery(cq);
q.setParameter(pLastName, "Janssen");
List<Tuple> authorBooks = q.getResultList();
```

Reference: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-left-join-fetch-join-criteriaquery/#Defining_a_LEFT_JOIN_or_RIGHT_JOIN_clause

Comment: @JCopetence thanks for your help can we achieve this same with JPA Specification.